# Capturing text after a certain character in a string python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python and i am trying to lean how regexs work. I would like to capture everything after the GT in this string:

`string = re.search(r"(GT\s*)(.)\n", notes)`

thanks for the help!

Edit: I would like the output to look like this:

`\s*)(.)\n", notes)`

Comment: show `notes` values and expected result

Comment: How about `r"GT(.+)"`?

Comment: Oh, wow, your string is `"re.search(r"(GT\s*)(.)\n", notes)"`? That's unexpected...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
s = 'string = re.search(r"(GT\s*)(.)\n", notes)'
m = re.search(r'GT(.*)', s, re.DOTALL)
print(m.group(1))
```

The output (contains line-break according to `\n` presence):

```
\s*)(.)
", notes)
```

Answer (score 0):

in below example every thing catch after @

```
 >>>import re
 >>>re.findall(r'@(\w+)', '@hi there @kallz @!')
 >>>['hi', 'kallz']
```